# Combination of Combinations

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I am working on solving a problem involving groups of combinations.

For example,

There are 25 males and 25 females involved in a study. Eight people are expected to be selected for this study. What is the probability of exactly 4 men and 4 women be selected out of the 50 people?

Clearly this is not the same problem. I am hoping to better understand this so that I can apply it as a general rule to similar problems I am trying to explain as a tutor in Algebra to a college student. I taught basic combinations from 2012-2013 but combinations of combinations are well beyond what I was teaching. Any suggestions on how to set up the problem in form?

My current guess to solving this sort of problem is setup in the following form.

$\frac{8!}{\binom{25}{4} * \binom{25}{4}}$

Answer (score 3):

Order doesn't matter here, so the $8!$ is unnecessary. Your idea is close though. We have $\binom{25}{4}$ ways to choose the men, and $\binom{25}{4}$ ways to choose the women. These are independent of each other, so we multiply them. There are $\binom{50}{8}$ ways to choose the participants, so that's the denominator:

$$ \frac{ \binom{25}{4} \binom{25}{4} } { \binom{50}{8}} $$

Comment: Thank you greatly for explaining this to me. The student I am tutoring has the textbook but I am afraid of all of my old textbooks in Stats do not get into these types of problems sufficiently in depth. Thank you greatly.

Comment: It might be worth investing in an introductory combinatorics text. It will give a better treatment of this material than a stats text will. Glad I was able to help!

Comment: Also, it might be worth noting that this is the Hypergeometric distribution.